# rmarkdown: how to use multiple bibliographies for a document

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

[My environment:  Win 7 Pro / R 3.2.1 / knitr_1.12.3 / R Studio Version 0.99.892]

I am trying to write an article in `.Rmd` format using R Studio, Knit -> PDF, and I've been following http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html for details of how to get `pandoc` and `pandoc-citeproc` to produce a References section and citations
in the text.

My BibTeX references are in several different `.bib` files, which, when using
LaTeX in `.Rnw` files, are all found in **my local texmf tree** via

```
\bibliography{statistics, graphics}
```

I can't seem to make this work with `pandoc-citeproc`.   My YAML header
has the following, that works for **one** `.bib` file, as long as it is
in the same directory as the source `.Rmd` file:

```
    ---
    title: "Notes on Testing Equality of Covariance Matrices"
    author: "Michael Friendly"
    date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%B %d, %Y")`'
    output:
      pdf_document:
        fig_caption: yes
        keep_tex: yes
        number_sections: yes
    csl: apa.csl
    bibliography: statistics.bib
    ---
```

Following advice in the link given above, I tried:

```
bibliography: [statistics.bib,graphics.bib]
```

this gives:

```
pandoc-citeproc.exe: "stdin" (line 50, column 12):
unexpected ":"
expecting letter, digit, white space or "="
pandoc.exe: Error running filter pandoc-citeproc
Filter returned error status 1
```

[Edit: For completeness, I show the generated `pandoc` command, where it looks like both .bib files are passed correctly]:

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS EqCov.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output EqCov.pdf --template "C:\R\R-3.2.1\library\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.15.2.tex" --number-sections --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" --bibliography statistics.bib --bibliography graphics.bib --filter pandoc-citeproc 
output file: EqCov.knit.md
```

So do all the following forms:

```
    bibliography: ["statistics.bib","graphics.bib"]

    bibliography: 
      - "statistics.bib"
      - "graphics.bib"

    bibliography: 
      - statistics.bib
      - graphics.bib
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use one of the following forms, and not have to copy the .bib files to the document directory.

```
bibliography: ["C:/Dropbox/localtexmf/bibtex/bib/statistics.bib","C:/Dropbox/localtexmf/bibtex/bib/graphics.bib"]

bibliography: 
 - "C:/Dropbox/localtexmf/bibtex/bib/statistics.bib"
 - "C:/Dropbox/localtexmf/bibtex/bib/graphics.bib"
```

Comment: Just a note - this seems to work without problems in HTML output. Has there been any update regardidng the pdf problem?

Comment: @user101089, although the "for a document" part of the question's title is somewhat helpful, the question can still be mistaken for asking about obtaining different bibliography/references sections, whereas it asks for using multiple bibliography source files. Perhaps, you would consider editing to improve clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record:  I raised this as an issue for pandoc-citeproc at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/issues/220

It turns out that there were problems in how `pandoc-citeproc` handles some characters in `@{string={}}` and non-ASCII characters in `.bib` files, so what I was trying now works, with hard-coded pathnames, in all the forms I tried.

To make it work more like processing of `.Rnw` files via Latex/bibtex it would be nice to be able to use something like

```
bibliography: 
  - `r system(kpsewhich statistics.bib)`
  - `r system(kpsewhich graphics.bib)`
```

Those commands *do* find the right files in an R session, but not from a YAML header.

Comment: I've found that R commands can (sometimes) be run from YAML headers by encapsulating them in single-quotes, so the following might work:

    `- '\`r system(kpsewhich statistics.bib)\`'`

For instance, this works for the YAML "date" header:

    `date: '\`r format(Sys.Date(), "%B %Y")\`'`