# add sub section with no used references in the reference section R Markdown

Tags: reference, r-markdown

I have created my thesis with R markdown and in the project created ( Database application) I have used 48 papers that I have to add the to references, I didnt mention them in the thesis I have just to add a sub title in the references called : `Used in the application` and put them all. my references list is created with `bibtex`

Is there a solution to import my references list with a subltitle in he references section knowing that I have other references That I already put in the references

My desired output may be like this

```
 References
   1 abcd
   2 efjh 
Used in the application
    1 xyz
    2tuv
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a second bibliography?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707298/how-to-get-a-second-bibliography)

Comment: Does my answer fit your needs? And why did you delete your other question where I provided an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `multibib` package to achieve this:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
header-includes:  
  - \usepackage{multibib}
  - \newcites{App}{Used in the application}
---

[@Brooks98]

\bibliography{bibliography}


\nociteApp{*}
\bibliographyApp{library}
```

Result using two bib files I had available:

[image]

Note that by not including `bibliography` in the YAML header I am tricking the system into not including the default reference section after the body. This gives me the freedom to include my own reference sections. One with my normal references from the `bibliography.bib`  and one section from `library.bib`. Via `\nociteApp{*}` I am citing all of them without leaving any mark in the text.