# Use citation() in R Markdown to automatically generate a bibliography of R packages

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to cite the R packages used in a project but since they are quite numerous, I think it would be a good idea to create two separate reference sections: one with the references of my specific domain and one with the references for the R packages.

My first idea would be to check if I can export all the citations of the packages used at once in a .bib file, but I'm not sure that R Markdown can handle both the .bib file with the bibliography of papers specific to my domain and the .bib file for the R packages.

Since the functions `citation()` or `toBibtex()` generate Bibtex citations, I thought it might be possible to generate the reference section dedicated to the R packages with these functions directly in the .Rmd file. However, it does not seem possible to automatically format a reference when these commands are included in a chunk with R Markdown.

Here's a reproducible example of the thing I'm trying to do:

````
---
title: "Cite R packages"
author: ""
date: "01/02/2020"
output: pdf_document
bibliography: test.bib
---

This is a citation of a paper: @mayer2011.

# Bibliography {-}
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
\noindent
<div id="refs"></div>
```{r refmgr references, results="asis", echo=FALSE}
# Print
```
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

# Bibliography for R packages {-}
```{r}
citation("dplyr")
toBibtex(citation("dplyr"))
```
````

and here's the content of `test.bib`:

```
@article{mayer2011,
  title = {Notes on {{CEPII}}'s {{Distances Measures}}: {{The GeoDist Database}}},
  shorttitle = {Notes on {{CEPII}}'s {{Distances Measures}}},
  journal = {SSRN Electronic Journal},
  doi = {10.2139/ssrn.1994531},
  author = {Mayer, Thierry and Zignago, Soledad},
  year = {2011}
}
```

Any idea about how to easily include the references of the R packages in a separate reference section?

**EDIT: see [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/use-citation-in-r-markdown-to-automatically-generate-a-bibliography-of-r-packages/51363/11) for another solution.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two seperate though related problems here:

1. How to cite a package programatically
2. How to have two seperate reference sections in your markdown document

There are solutions to both of them which I'll go over in turn:

---

### How to cite a package programatically

The key here is realising that Pandoc will only write your document *after* the R code chunks have run. This gives you the opportunity of writing a `.bib` file programatically as part of your R markdown document, which is only read by Pandoc at the document creation stage.

It also depends on being able to use two `.bib` files in your bibliography. This is also possible, but we'll leave that issue for now.

What you need is a function that will take package names, get the bibtex-formatted citations, paste them all together and save them as a `.bib` file. I have written an example function here to show how that could be done.

This function has to handle packages that spit out multiple bibtex citations, and it will automatically insert the package name in bibtex so that you can reference any package in your markdown with @packagename. It uses non-standard evaluation and the `...` arguments so that you don't need to quote the package names or wrap them in `c()`:

```
citeR <- function(...)
{
  packages <- unlist(lapply(as.list(match.call()), deparse))[-1]
  Rbibs <- ""

  for(package in packages)
  {
    Rbib <- capture.output(print(citation(package), bibtex = T))    
    Rbib <- mapply(function(x, y) Rbib[x:y], 
                   grep("  @.+[{]", Rbib), 
                   which(Rbib == "  }"))

    if(class(Rbib) == "matrix"){
      Rbib[1, 1] <- gsub(",", paste0(package, ","), Rbib[1, 1])
      Rbib <- paste0(Rbib, collapse = "\n")
    } else {
      Rbib <- unlist(lapply(Rbib, function(x) {
                               x[1] <- gsub(",", paste0(package, ","), x[1]); 
                               x <- paste0(unlist(x), collapse = "\n")
                               return(x)
                             }))
    }

    if(length(Rbib) > 1) {
      if(any(grepl("@Manual", Rbib))) {
        Rbib <- Rbib[grep("@Manual", Rbib)][1]
      } else {
        Rbib <- Rbib[1]}}

    Rbibs <- paste(Rbibs, Rbib, sep = "\n\n")
  }

  writeBin(charToRaw(utf8::as_utf8(Rbibs)), "packages.bib")
}
```

To use it you would just put it in an R chunk with an echo = FALSE and do this:

```
citeR(dplyr, ggplot2, knitr, pROC)
```

---

### How to have two reference sections

I cannot take credit for this part of the answer, which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707298/how-to-get-a-second-bibliography). It is more involved than the first part. First of all, you must use a lua filter, and this requires the most up to date versions of rmarkdown and Pandoc so **please update to the lastest versions or this may not work**.

The rationale for the lua filter is described in the provided link, but I will include it here with full acknowledgement to @tarleb. You must save the following file as `multiple-bibliographies.lua` in the same directory as your markdown:

```lua
-- file: multiple-bibliographies.lua

--- collection of all cites in the document
local all_cites = {}
--- document meta value
local doc_meta = pandoc.Meta{}

--- Create a bibliography for a given topic. This acts on all divs whose ID
-- starts with "refs", followed by nothings but underscores and alphanumeric
-- characters.
local function create_topic_bibliography (div)
  local name = div.identifier:match('^refs([_%w]*)$')
  if not name then
    return nil
  end
  local tmp_blocks = {
    pandoc.Para(all_cites),
    pandoc.Div({}, pandoc.Attr('refs')),
  }
  local tmp_meta = pandoc.Meta{bibliography = doc_meta['bibliography' .. name]}
  local tmp_doc = pandoc.Pandoc(tmp_blocks, tmp_meta)
  local res = pandoc.utils.run_json_filter(tmp_doc, 'pandoc-citeproc')
  -- first block of the result contains the dummy para, second is the refs Div
  div.content = res.blocks[2].content
  return div
end

local function resolve_doc_citations (doc)
  -- combine all bibliographies
  local meta = doc.meta
  local orig_bib = meta.bibliography
  meta.bibliography = pandoc.MetaList{orig_bib}
  for name, value in pairs(meta) do
    if name:match('^bibliography_') then
      table.insert(meta.bibliography, value)
    end
  end
  doc = pandoc.utils.run_json_filter(doc, 'pandoc-citeproc')
  doc.meta.bibliography = orig_bib -- restore to original value
  return doc
end

return {
  {
    Cite = function (c) all_cites[#all_cites + 1] = c end,
    Meta = function (m) doc_meta = m end,
  },
  {Pandoc = resolve_doc_citations,},
  {Div = create_topic_bibliography,}
}
```

To get this to work, your YAML header should look like this:

```
---
title: "Cite R packages"
author: ''
date: "01/02/2020"
output:
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: --lua-filter=multiple-bibliographies.lua
bibliography_software: packages.bib
bibliography_normal: test.bib
---
```

Note that `packages.bib` doesn't need to exist when you start knitting the document, since it will be created before Pandoc is called.

To insert the references sections, you need put these html snippets at the appropriate points of your markdown:

```html
<div id = "refs_normal"></div>
```

and

```html
<div id = "refs_software"></div>
```

---

### Putting it all together

I know this is already a long answer, but I thought it would be good to include a full working example and show the pdf output:

````r
---
title: "Cite R packages"
author: ''
date: "01/02/2020"
output:
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: --lua-filter=multiple-bibliographies.lua
bibliography_software: packages.bib
bibliography_normal: test.bib
---

This is a citation of a paper: @mayer2011.
This is a citation of an R package @dplyr
And another @ggplot2 and another @knitr plus @pROC

# Bibliography{-}
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
\noindent
<div id = "refs_normal"></div>
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

# Software used{-}
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
\noindent
<div id = "refs_software"></div>
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

```{r citeR, echo=FALSE}

citeR <- function(...)
{
  packages <- unlist(lapply(as.list(match.call()), deparse))[-1]
  Rbibs <- ""

  for(package in packages)
  {
    Rbib <- capture.output(print(citation(package), bibtex = T))

    Rbib <- mapply(function(x, y) Rbib[x:y], 
                   grep("  @.+[{]", Rbib), 
                   which(Rbib == "  }"))

    if(class(Rbib) == "matrix")
    {
      Rbib[1, 1] <- gsub(",", paste0(package, ","), Rbib[1, 1])
      Rbib <- paste0(Rbib, collapse = "\n")
    }
    else
    {
      Rbib <- unlist(lapply(Rbib, function(x) {
                               x[1] <- gsub(",", paste0(package, ","), x[1]); 
                               x <- paste0(unlist(x), collapse = "\n")
                               return(x)
                             }))
    }

    if(length(Rbib) > 1)
    {
      if(any(grepl("@Manual", Rbib)))
      {
        Rbib <- Rbib[grep("@Manual", Rbib)][1]
      }
      else
      {
        Rbib <- Rbib[1]
      }
    }

    Rbibs <- paste(Rbibs, Rbib, sep = "\n\n")
  }

  writeBin(charToRaw(utf8::as_utf8(Rbibs)), "packages.bib")
}

citeR(dplyr, ggplot2, knitr, pROC)

```#
````

and test.pdf looks like this:

[image]

If you would rather automatically cite any packages you use, you could programatically scrape the names from any calls to `library()` in your markdown document. Since the workflow for achieving your goal is a little convoluted, you might want to consider creating a small package with the `citeR` function, the lua document and your own `get_lib_citations_from_library_calls("my_markdown.Rmd")` function that automates all of this.

Comment: this is really great and thanks a lot for the explanation too! Just an additional question: do you know how to change the citation style?

Comment: @bretauv you use biblio-style: [style] in the YAML

Comment: not working, I tried with ```alphabetic```, ```[alphabetic]``` and ```"alphabetic"```

Comment: @bretauv personally, I use csl files - see https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html#citation_styles

Comment: Hi, it seems that the `csl` file is not applied everywhere. In particular, the citation style in the text corresponds but not the references in bibliography. For example, I tried to apply [this csl format](https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=Chicago%20Manual%20of%20Style%2017th%20edition%20(author-date)%2C%20French). It correctly adds "et" between author names in the text, but it does not replace "and" by "et" in the bibliography (for both bibliographies). Do you how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you:

````
---
title: "Cite R packages"
author: ""
date: "01/02/2020"
output: pdf_document
bibliography: test.bib
---

This is a citation of a paper: @mayer2011. 

# Bibliography {-}
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
\noindent
<div id="refs"></div>
```{r refmgr references, results="asis", echo=FALSE}
# Print
```
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

# Bibliography for R packages {-}
```{r, results = "asis", echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

# library(devtools)
# install_github("cboettig/knitcitations")

library("knitcitations")

tmpfile <- 'rtext.bib'

pkgs <- c('dplyr', 'tidyverse')

citations <- do.call('c',lapply(pkgs, citation))

knitcitations::write.bibtex(citations, file = tmpfile)

knitcitations::read.bibtex(file = 'rtest.bib')

```
````

Comment: This is nice but the citations coming from `knitcitations` don't follow the `csl` format (when I add one in YAML), whereas the citations coming from `test.bib` follow this format. Do you know why and how to fix it?