# Add a secondary list of bibliography titled "My Publications"

Tags: pandoc, beamer, bibliography

I was doing a pandoc beamer presentation, and have already inserted a bibliography. I have to insert another set of bibliographic citations that includes "My publications" that has to exist on a seperate frame. Is this possible in pandoc / beamer or should I do a manual add? What I am currently doing is like below and looking to automate the data in `# My Publications` with automated citations that exist in the bib file I use. Thanks!

```
---
title: One Tests pandoc beamer doing a presentation
bibliography: mybib.bib
suppress-bibliography: true

---

# My First Slide
This can be addressed as [@SomeCite_1992]

# My Second Slide
Another study shows that this can be done [@OtherCite_2020]

# References
(pandoc maual says div marked as #refs will be filled with biblio)
::: {#refs}

:::

# My publications

Me Myself, A Colleague, The Professor, "Hard-found evidence that this is not hugely important", J. Awesome studies, Feb 2019.

Me Myself, Another dude, The Professor, "Some crazy study that means nothing", J. None Reads, Dec 2020.
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a second bibliography?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707298/how-to-get-a-second-bibliography)

Comment: @tarleb Thanks for the pointer, and this is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Unbelivable this never showed up on hours of search! But now i have to figure out how to make it work with  github:jalvesaq/zotcite which i use for integrating vim-zotero-pandoc. In case I figure it out, I will edit this post and [solved] it.