# Include extra bibliography in R Markdown

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, bibliography

I am writing my dissertation using R Markdown (output: Word) and have my primary bibliography from which all citations are based. This renders with no issue:

yaml:

```
---
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
     base_format: "bookdown::word_document2"
     reference_docx: template.docx
     pandoc_args: [ "--csl", "apa.csl"]
bibliography: references.bib
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
---
```

However, in my appendix, I'd also like to include a separate list of references to cite all the packages I used, packcages.bib. I cannot seem to find an easy way of adding an additional bibliography. I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707298/how-to-get-a-second-bibliography) but it produced too many encoding errors. I thought of just rendering a separate Word file and attaching/inserting it into the appendix, but did not find a function that could do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of an external Word file can be included in R Markdown via `officer::block_pour_docx`. I used Zotero to generate a Word bibliography based on pacakges.bib and then the following to include in my document:

````
```{r}
block_pour_docx("packages.docx")
```
````