# knitr/Rmarkdown/pandoc : How to set bibliography paths globally in .Rmd files

Tags: yaml, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

[**FYI**: This question is related to [rmarkdown: how to use multiple bibliographies for a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202023/rmarkdown-how-to-use-multiple-bibliographies-for-a-document])

In LaTeX documemnts or even in Rmarkdown `.Rnw`, I can simply use something like

```
\bibliography{graphics, statistics, timeref}
```

to have BibTeX search for the files `graphics.bib`, `statistics.bib`, and `timeref.bib`
under my local `texmf` directories.

In a `.Rmd` file, using a `yaml` header, I'm forced to list each bibliography file using either
absolute paths (not portable), or relative paths (clunky, error-prone).  Here is one recent example:

```
---
title: "My Cool Paper"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  html_document

bibliography:
  - "../../../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/graphics.bib"
  - "../../../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/statistics.bib"
  - "../../../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/timeref.bib"
---
```

**Question**: Just as I can use `r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')` to use R to fill in the date, can I use some R expression to find/fill-in the paths to my .bib files under `bibliography:`?

OK, from the earlier question, I tried using

```
bibliography:
  - "`r system('kpsewhich graphics.bib')`"
  - "`r system('kpsewhich statistics.bib')`"
  - "`r system('kpsewhich timeref.bib')`"
```

This finds the correct paths, but just generates them as output in the R markdown log, rather than into the `yaml` header.  I see:

```
processing file: Vis-MLM.Rmd
  |........                                                              |  11%
   inline R code fragments

C:/Users/friendly/Dropbox/localtexmf/bibtex/bib/graphics.bib
C:/Users/friendly/Dropbox/localtexmf/bibtex/bib/statistics.bib
C:/Users/friendly/Dropbox/localtexmf/bibtex/bib/timeref.bib
```

Comment: Interesting question! Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707298/how-to-get-a-second-bibliography) post?

Comment: Yes, I've seen that post, but it (doesn't really) answer a different question.  This and similar questions expose flaws/limitations  in the `yaml` -> {`r-markdown`, `pandoc-citeproc`} chain.  I posted this because I thought there was perhaps a clever work around for the particular problem I described.

Answer (score 5):

I nearly had it right, but forgot `intern=TRUE`

This works:

```
bibliography:
  - "`r system('kpsewhich graphics.bib', intern=TRUE)`"
  - "`r system('kpsewhich statistics.bib', intern=TRUE)`"
  - "`r system('kpsewhich timeref.bib', intern=TRUE)`"
```

Comment: That's actually helpful to include the bibliography by a relative path. In my case, the reference file was in the parent directory, so
```bibliography:
  - "`r system('kpsewhich ../references.bib', intern = TRUE)`"
```
did it :)