# Quarto: How to search for bibliography files using `system(kpsewhich( ...))`

Tags: yaml, knitr, pandoc, quarto, pandoc-citeproc

This is a follow-up to [knitr/Rmarkdown/pandoc : How to set bibliography paths globally in .Rmd files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447367/knitr-rmarkdown-pandoc-how-to-set-bibliography-paths-globally-in-rmd-files/) where a solution that works with `knitr/rmarkdown/pandoc` does NOT work with Quarto.

I have multiple `.bib` files in a system-wide `localtexmf` folder. I want to specify that some of these are searched for references in a quarto document. (I don't want to have to copy each of these to the project folder or specify full absolute or relative paths to these files.)

With `knitr/rmarkdown/pandoc` I can use:

```
bibliography:
- references.bib
- "`r system('kpsewhich graphics.bib', intern=TRUE)`"
- "`r system('kpsewhich statistics.bib', intern=TRUE)`"
- "`r system('kpsewhich timeref.bib', intern=TRUE)`"
```

However, using Quarto, this gives an error:

```
Preparing to preview
[1/2] intro.qmd
File r system('kpsewhich graphics.bib', intern=TRUE) not found in resource path
```

The `system(kpsewhich())` command **does** find the files in the console:

```
> system('kpsewhich graphics.bib')
C:/Users/friendly/Dropbox/localtexmf/bibtex/bib/graphics.bib
[1] 0
```

How can I make this work using Quarto? Is there something different with the YAML syntax for Quarto? Is there some other way?

**Edit**:
This may be a more general problem of using `r function()` in YAML with Quarto.  This attempt to set the `date:` doesn't give an error, but yields
**Invalid date** in the rendered book.

```
  date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
```

[This is now **solved**, using `!expr format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')` as suggested by @shafee.

**Testing PDF**:

Rendering to PDF gives more clues about why even the `!expr` solution doesn't work with Quarto.  In the console, I get:

```
  bibliography:
    - references.bib
    - tag: '!expr'
      value: system('kpsewhich graphics.bib'
    - intern=TRUE)
    - tag: '!expr'
      value: system('kpsewhich statistics.bib'
    - tag: '!expr'
      value: system('kpsewhich timeref.bib'
  date:
    tag: '!expr'
    value: 'format(Sys.time(), ''%B %d, %Y'')'
  
File intern=TRUE) not found in resource path
```

so Quarto seems to have trouble parsing the `system()` call with the `intern=TRUE` option.  This seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like this under bibliography yaml key,

```
- !expr system('kpsewhich graphics.bib', intern=TRUE)
```

I haven't tested this but my hunch is, since quarto uses different syntax ([see here](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/r.html#chunk-options)) for evaluating R-code in yaml, maybe that's why it's thinking the given command in `` "`r ...`" `` as a file, instead of R-code.

Comment: Good suggestion! This seems to work, in that it does not generate an error.  However, it does not find the references from my `.bib` files; I get a warning: **[WARNING] Citeproc: citation Timm:75 not found**.  I'll have to investigate further ...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't make any more hunchs about the warning you are having. :-)